# Пунктуация в предложении с союзом "если... то"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, сложное-предложение

**Постарайтесь посетить и осмотреть(?) если не все(?) то(?) хотя бы(?) самые крупные музеи искусств Дрездена.**

Объясните, пожалуйста, постановку каждого знака препинания: почему стоит запятая или не стоит. Желательно с кратким описанием правил.

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить его галочкой.

Comment: Между прочим это не повтор вопроса. Здесь союз если ..то является сопоставительным, а там условным. В данном случае слова ***если не все*** являются не придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения, а частью простого предложения.

Answer (score 1):

В предложении "Постарайтесь посетить и осмотреть если не все, то хотя бы самые крупные музеи искусств Дрездена" **союз "если ...то"** соединяет однородные члены предложения, поэтому  запятая ставится только перед второй частью союза.

Слово **хотя бы** в данном случае является частицей и запятой не выделяется.

Answer (score 0):

***Постарайтесь посетить и осмотреть если не все, то хотя бы самые крупные музеи искусств Дрездена.***

"Хотя бы" может быть частицей или союзом (у нас - усилительная частица), ни в одном случае не требует обособлений.

Если... то - составной союз, запятая всегда нужна перед "то", перед "если" ставится только по условиям контекста, то есть когда она узда для пунктуации начала фразы.